# Do printing functions use CPU, when nobody listen to their output?

Tags: android, optimization, android-ndk, stdout, logcat

I came across this problem today.
Generally speaking, using lots of prints to the screen or file (ie: stdout). Does use CPU and in some cases can limit the speed of your application. This is even more critical in mobile devices, due to the limitations of HW.

However, how does the OS/library handle the case where no-one is listening to the output of it? Does it get called and trashed? Does it not?. I can think of many cases where this may happen and therefore it can be a waste of cycles.

I can give you 2 cases I have special interest on:

1. Android NDK application printing to the `std::cout`
2. Android app (NDK or Java) printing to Logcat, but no `adb` connected.

If that is not the case, I should start removing prints to stdout in my JNI apps, which is a huge amount of work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do, but it's not much.  This is why you can connect a device and read Logcat entries that were created before the connection took place.